# Get Multiple Image Files From A Directory

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a Flask Web Application and there is a **POST** API name, `/getImages` to which it returns the path and the actual name of 10 images based on my input query.

Now the problem is that there are 10000 images and it wouldn't be good way to place all the images into the `static` directory.

There is a method in a flask `send_from_directory`

```
@app.route('/<path:filename>')  
def send_file(filename):  
    return send_from_directory(app.image_folder, filename)
```

which can be configured to access my images from any directory. But the problem is that I need to call this API multiple times (In my case 10 times).

Is there any workaround to get the 10 images in one API call?

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`send_from_directory` returns a single file, so you could either call your `send_file` function in for loop for all the files in your image folder directory using `os.listdir(images_path)` or return a .zip file of your images.